# Assert function to check only value from the arrays are contained in the list

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Could you please help me,

I have a list and an array:

```
String[] list = new String[] {"milk", "tea", "milk", "tea", "milk", "tea"};
String[] t = new String[] {"milk", "tea"};
```

I need to verify only the values from t (milk and tea) is contained in the  list, and not any other values example, the string doesn't have any other value like coffee or cookie.

I used

```
 for(int i=0; i< t.length; t++)
 {
 Assert.assertTrue(list.contains(t[i]));
 }
```

But this verifies only if the list contains the values from array. I need to verify it contains "only" them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused as to what your question is, your code seems to do what you want it to do? Does it not?

Comment: I agree with the above made comment.You seem to achieve your requirement. you need to elaborate if it is something else.

Comment: I have modified the question, in short I need to verify that the string doesn't have anything other than the values in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use [`removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)). From the docs,

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

A simple example

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("milk", "tea", "milk", "tea", "milk", "tea"));
ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("milk", "tea"));
list.removeAll(t);
System.out.println(list);
```

This prints `[]`.

To show you what a failure looks like.

```
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("extra", "milk", "tea", "milk", "tea", "milk", "tea"));
ArrayList<String> t2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("milk", "tea"));
list2.removeAll(t2);
System.out.println(list2);
```

This prints `[extra]`.

You can do a simple assert that `list.size()` is 0. If it's not 0, you know there are extra items in `list` that are not in `t`.

Comment: This is so brilliant! Thanks a ton @JeffC

Comment: From what i can see, you are actually deleting all items from the list. How do you propose to recover the original data set?

Comment: @JPadley You are assuming OP needs the original dataset after the assert. If he does, he can make a copy of the original set and use the code above. He's accepted the answer so I'm assuming he doesn't need the original dataset or has already adapted the code to his scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@Test
public void goodListTest() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("milk", "tea", "milk", "tea", "milk", "tea");
    String[] t = new String[] { "milk", "tea" };

    for (String item : list) {
        Assert.assertTrue(arrayContains(t, item));
    }

}

@Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
public void badListTest() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("milk", "randomvalue", "tea", "milk", "tea", "milk", "tea");
    String[] t = new String[] { "milk", "tea" };

    for (String item : list) {
        Assert.assertTrue(arrayContains(t, item));
    }

}

public boolean arrayContains(String[] arr, String value) {
    for (String item : arr) {
        if (item.equals(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`goodListTest` is a method which has a correct list, and tests that. That test passed. `badListTest` is a method which has an incorrect list and expects an `AssertionError` to be thrown.

We check if the array contains a specified value of the list, that way we know for sure it only matches those items.

Comment: But, here the size of the list is 6 and the array is 2. How it will work?

Comment: @ToDoGirl You're right I don't know what I was thinking, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by iterating through your lists, then using a nested `for` loop as such:

```
    String[] list = new String[] {"milk", "tea", "milk", "tea", "milk", "tea"};
    String[] t = new String[] {"milk", "tea"};

    boolean result = true;
    for(String item : list) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for(String check : t) {
            if(item.equals(check)) flag = true;
        }
        if(!flag) {
            result = false; 
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Through this method, the `result` variable will return `true` if the array contains only elements from `t`. This is done by checking each item in the list and making sure it is equal to at least one item from `t`.

If you like, you can `assert` on the result of this being `true` to throw an `AssertException` when the list contains other items.

Hope this helped!